# Get the windows domain of the logged in user (for a website)

Tags: javascript, php, windows, dns

I have to redirect users of my website according to the domain of his computer. If his position is domain "A" he is redirected to the website A. If his position is domain "B" he is redirected to the website B.

I searched everywhere, I do not find how to do it. I can not go through ActiveX for security reasons.

I tried to use the php function gethostbyaddr but it return only my ip when i connect to the site.

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by the users domain?

Comment: Do you mean which network domain their computer is logged into in their AD?

Comment: Yes i mean which network domain their computer is logged into in their AD

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse Windows domains with Internet (DNS) domains. A 'host' is an Internet domain (e.g. google.com).

There are no web standards to access Microsoft's proprietary network domain names.  You can access the User Agent to read some basic info about the browser and OS, but that doesn't include the Windows domain AFAIK.

Unless you are looking to do some hacky old-school stuff (read Internet Explorer) then this is not something you will be able to do.  I suggest considering other approaches, such as leveraging the User Agent and using a tool like [Bowser](http://lancedikson.github.io/bowser/docs/Bowser.html).